# Query Fusion Tables with JavaScript and pick 3 random items

Tags: javascript, random, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Fusion Tables to store a URL to my Google Drive Photos (stored in the column Link).

I'm using JavaScript to query Fusion Tables to get all the URLs and then create a table with 3 items picked randomly from the data.

The code I add underneath let me see 3 first photos ... I have tried to switch the line

```
contentStr += "<td><img src=" + item[j]+"></td>";
```

to

```
contentStr += "<td><img src=" + randomElement[j]+"></td>";
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone can help me please?

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
    function handler(response) {
      var maxFoto = response.rows.length
      var contentStr = "<table>";
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var item = response.rows[i];
          var randomFoto = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxFoto);
          var randomElement = item[randomFoto];
        contentStr += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
          contentStr += "<td><img src=" + item[j]+"></td>";
        }
        contentStr += "</tr>";
      }
      contentStr += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentStr;
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT%20Link%20FROM%20MYidTABLE&key=MYKEY&callback=handler&viewable=true"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello,

In what was doesn't it work?  Are there any errors on the console?

Please be as specific as possible in order to get an answer.

Comment: My apologies - the review queues don't make the answers as obvious as they might :)

Answer (score 0):

I give myself an answer ... code below works perfect!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
    function handler(response) {
      var maxFoto = response.rows.length
      var contentStr = "<table>";
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        var randomFoto = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxFoto);
        var item = response.rows[randomFoto];
        contentStr += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
          contentStr += "<td><img src=" + item[j]+"></td>";
        }
        contentStr += "</tr>";
      }
      contentStr += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentStr;
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT%20Link%20FROM%20MYTABLEID&key=MYKEY&callback=handler&viewable=true"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```